# How is /a/ pronounced before n/m in French?

Tags: prononciation, voyelles, nasalisation

Collins dictionary says that "panneau" is pronounced [pano] and "art" [aʁ]. However, the [a] in "panneau" does not sound like the [a] in art, but rather more nasal. Am I listening that right? If so, why is the nasal sound of "panneau" not represented in the phonemic/phonetic transcription provided by French dictionaries?

Comment: Well, not an answer because it's just my personal experience but I don't see any difference in the 2 [a]. However, the pronunciation is a difficult subject in French (as in a lot of languages I guess) because people from 2 regions can tell a word in 2 different way. So maybe it's the same for me but not for 20% or maybe 80% of France.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The widespread pronunciation is **[pano]** with no nasalisation. You might hear **[panɔ]** in eastern France, but this is unrelated to your question.

A non native speaker might hear a slight kind of nasalization at the end of the vowel **a** due to the transition to a nasal consonant. This is probably what you experienced but native French ears cannot hear it, or at least won't assimilate it to a nasalization.

There is an exception about this lack of nasalization but it doesn't really apply to *panneau*. It is the pronunciation used by a few people, generally old, from the Occitanie region (e.g. Toulouse, Montpellier) who might still nasalize the sequence **an** or **am** before an **n** or a **m**  leading to **[ɑ̃n]** (or better **[ɑ̃n.n]**) instead of the usual **[an]**. This used to be the standard French pronunciation before this nasalisation disappeared a few centuries ago.

For example, *grammaire* and *grand-mère* used to be pronounced identically.

> — Veux-tu toute ta vie offenser la grammaire ?
>   — Qui parle d'offenser grand'mère ni grand'père ?
>
> Molière, *Les femmes savantes*, acte II, scène 6, 1672.

And this might still be the case with some native speakers:

https://www.bfmtv.com/mediaplayer/video/grammaire-ou-grand-mere-incomprehension-lors-du-point-presse-de-castaner-950001.html

Another typical example is ***année*** sometimes pronounced **[ɑ̃n.ne]** instead of **[ane]**.

With *panneau*, you might hear rares **[panno]** is southern France, but **[pɑ̃n.no]** is not expected.

Comment: Tu interpoles à partir du cas de « grammaire » ? Parce que s'il existe, le cas de [pɑ̃.no] est surement beaucoup plus rare. Une gémination sans nasalisation par contre c'est bien possible.

Comment: @stéphaneGimenez Non, j'ai connu quelqu'un qui prononçait tous les "ann" comme ça. C'était par exemple manifeste avec *année*.

Comment: Oui « année » aussi, je suis familier avec ça (natif de Toulouse), mais « panneau » ça m'étonne plus (je ne parle pas de la légère nasalisation naturelle qui précède les *n*). Je vois tout aussi mal quelqu'un prononcer « anneau » avec une nasalisation.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Tu as raison, je me suis en effet un peu trop avancé. La nasalisation n'a pas vraiment de justification pour *panneau* ou *anneau*, les mots occitans correspondant ne doublant pas le n (*panèl*, *anèl*).

Answer (score 4):

The two are pronounced the same. The nasal sound might come from the double 'n', but that's beyond my expertise (and the question).

Reference : french is my mother tongue.

Comment: I wouldn't use *french is my mother tongue* as a reference, since it may be right here, but what if someone ask for *rose* ? Or *lait* ? I mean, I always said these words the same way, but some region in France doesn't have the same pronunciation. And there's one twhich is written in *valid* (written somewhere) and the other which because of the accent of the region. What if you're in the region that pronounce it *bad* and think it's the same while in reality it's not supposed to be.

Comment: @JackRed I agree with most of your comment but I wouldn't use *bad* or *(in)valid* about regional pronunciation. They are just different. A *bad/invalid* pronunciation is one that doesn't follow any native French standard (thus saying \art\ for *art* is invalid). "Accent-less" (note the quotes) Parisian French is just another regional variation as far as linguistics are concerned. Unlike the orthography, the pronunciation present in dictionaries is more informative than prescriptive.

Comment: @jlliagre yeah I understand. I put bad and valid in emphasis because I didn't know what term to use (it's not really visible nor understandable tho, quotes are better). I though that dictionaries pronunciation was more prescriptive than informative, thanks for the information

Comment: I see what you meant, I was referring to french "neutral" accent (which admittedly isn't formally defined as far as i know)

Comment: I can hear a somewhat nasal A sound in the pronunciation example in https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/panneau. Maybe it's just my bad hearing then.

Comment: You can ask basically any native who isn't a linguist, they will tell you the the *r* in “rapide” and the *r* in “parti” are pronounced the same. Yet you would be misinformed.

Comment: They are indeed the same to me (I'm not a native though). How is this related to my question? Could you be more explicit please?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista: In many languages (English, for one) vowels which are before a nasal consonant sometimes acquire a slight nasalization. Even if this is happening with that pronunciation example of *panneau*, it is much less than the phonemic nasalization of *pain* or *pense*. And French speakers clearly don't hear it, so you can ignore it.

Answer (score 3):

Petite vidéo avec les deux prononciations.

https://youtu.be/OBMHxUHlcpU

Comment: Bonjour ! Pourrais-tu stp. préciser, s'agit-il de deux prononciations distinctes ou des deux mots prononcés ?

Comment: Bonjour,
Non, il s'agit de la même prononciation pour le "a".

Comment: @GwenBrd modifie ta réponse pour inclure ton commentaire.