# Tendances dans la prononciation du redoublement graphique des consonnes du mot « grammaire » ?

Tags: prononciation, orthographe, phonétique, nasalisation

En ce qui a trait à la prononciation du mot [*grammaire*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/grammaire#Prononciation) (/gʁa.mɛʁ/
ou /ɡʁam.mɛʁ/), je lis au [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/grammaire) que :

> Le redoublement graphique de la consonne est en effet le signe d'une
>   ancienne nasalisation de l'initiale, dénasalisée à partir du
>   17<sup>e</sup> siècle.

- Est-ce que ça veut dire que depuis le 17<sup>e</sup> on prononce de
  plus en plus gʁa.mɛʁ ; peut-on expliquer ?
- Comment nomme-t-on la « différence de prononciation » entre /gʁa.mɛʁ/
  et /ɡʁam.mɛʁ/ ?
- Laquelle de ces prononciations est la plus courante quand il n'y a pas [nasalisation](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/37309) (en tenant compte des nuances qui s'imposent) ?

Comment: C'est « gémination » le terme que tu cherches pour le 2e point.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez N'hésite pas à formuler une réponse !

Answer (score 1):

Je dirais que /ɡʁamɛʁ/ plutôt que /ɡʁam:ɛʁ/ est la prononciation la plus courante.  Le français ne connaît pas vraiment les consonnes dites doubles dans la prononciation.  *Double* est impropre, le son consonantique étant tout simplement tenu plus longtemps, d'où ma transcription du phénomène par /:/ suivant le son concerné.

Il n'est pas facile de savoir comment se prononçait le français au XVIIème siècle.  On trouve néanmoins dans la *Grammaire françoise rapportée au langage du temps* (1633) d'Oudin les remarques suivantes :

- Double m se prononce comme simple.
- Deux nn se prononcent comme une simple.

Cela me conforte dans l'idée que le /m:/ de /ɡʁam:ɛʁ/ est une aberration.  Je précise que je ne donne aucune connotation négative à *aberration*.

Sur la dénasalisation, Brunot et Bruneau dans leur *Précis de grammaire historique de la langue française* disent :

« Au XVIe et au XVIIe siècle une voyelle nasale suivie d'une consonne nasale perd sa nasalité :

- *annata(m) > année (1° /ane/; 2° /ɑ̃ne/; 3° /ane/)

Dès 1562, Ramus écrit *Jane* /ʒan/ avec un seul *n* et non *Jeanne* /ʒɑ̃n/, gramère /gʁamɛʁ/ et non grammaire /gʁɑ̃mɛʁ/.  Mais chez Molière, Bélise, une savante, prononçait /gʁɑ̃mɛʁ/, sinon la réplique de Martine (*Femmes savantes*, II, 6) : *Qui parle d'offenser grand-père ni grand-mère*, n'aurait plus de sens.

Il semble donc qu'à Paris même, l'hésitation entre les formes nasalisées (plus distinguées?) et les formes dénasalisées (plus populaires?) ait duré plus longtemps.

Notez que le Midi de la France a conservé aujourd'hui encore la prononciation /ɑ̃ne/. »

Comment: L'article Wikipédia sur le [français du Québec](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ais_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois), pas plus que le sous-article sur sa [prononciation](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prononciation_du_fran%C3%A7ais_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois) ne contiennent le terme « gémination » mais l'article wiktionnaire pour _grammaire_ dit « Québec (Populaire) : [ɡʁam.maɛ̯ʁ] ». Peut-être que c'est ma région (sud-ouest) au Québec qui correspond avec le parler populaire. Ce sont des sujets que je maîtrise très peu, d'où ma question...