# Why is commandant kɔ.mɑ̃.dɑ̃ and not kɔ̃.mɑ̃.dɑ̃?

Tags: prononciation, orthographe

According to the French orthography page on Wikipedia, -om becomes ɔ̃ before a consonant (m in this case). So why is ɔ̃ not allowed? Is it because of some syllable breakdown rule that I am not aware of or is it because while m is technically a consonant, the French orthography rule doesn't treat it like one?

Comment: The rule doesn't apply to double m or double n, and it also doesn't seem to apply to the combination mn  — consider the words *hymne*, *amnésie*, the prefix *omni-* (and probably a lot of other words I can't think of right now).

Answer (score 5):

This is French. Rules have exceptions. A vowel followed by N or M which is followed a *different* consonant or at the end of the word becomes a nasal vowel. There are a few exceptions: `-mn` does not lead to nasalization, the final `-um` (or `-ums`) is pronounced /ɔm/, recent imports from foreign languages are not nasalized, and probably a few more I can't think of right now.

A double consonnant does not nasalize the preceding vowel except in the few cases where it does. The only exception I can think of is when the prefix `-en` was added to a word beginning with `n` or `m` (in the latter case, the word is spelled `emm-`), with some fluctuation when `en-` was derived from the Latin prefix `in-`. Here are a few examples which are nasalized:

> ennui /ɑ̃.nɥi/
> enneigé /ɑ̃.nɛ.ʒe/
> emmener /ɑ̃.mə.ne/
> remmener /ʁɑ̃.mə.ne/

But in other words the usual rule applies (`e` + double consonant is pronounced with an open /ɛ/ (è sound), occasionally a closed /e/ (é sound)):

> ennemi /ɛ.nə.mi/
> renne /ʁɛn/
> flemme /flɛm/
> emmental /ɛ.mɛ̃.tal/ or /e.mɛ̃.tal/
> Emmanuelle /ɛ.ma.nɥɛl/ or /e.ma.nɥɛl/

Also `emm` is pronounced /am/ in *femme* and in adverbs that end in `-emment`.

Comment: A few other ones: *emmagasiner, emmailloter, emmancher, emmerder, emmitoufler, emmurer, emmener, emménager, emmêler, ennoblir*

Comment: Notice that there are regional variants. For instance in Languedoc, _année_ is pronounced  /ɑ̃.nɛ/.

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected pronunciation, along with [co.mɑ̃.dɑ̃] and variations in the way /ɑ̃/ is realized.

Most nasal vowels directly followed by a nasal consonant (i.e. *N* or *M*) lost their nasality several centuries ago.

There are rare regional exceptions (See [How is /a/ pronounced before n/m in French?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/37309/how-is-a-pronounced-before-n-m-in-french)) and a few other ones, as Gilles rightly pointed out in [his answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/45431/1109).